# Phalcon Micro Collection - action not running in controller

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm having a problem setting up Micro collections with Phalcon. I want controllers to handle the requests but, when I use setHandler() on the micro collection, and then map the route, nothing happens when making a request.

Code in public/index.php is as follows:

```
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection as MicroCollection;

try {

    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        '../app/controllers/',
        '../app/models/',
        '../app/libraries/'
    ))->register();

    $app = new Micro();

    $col = new MicroCollection();

    $col->setHandler(new PostsController());

    $col->get('/', 'index');

    $app->mount($col);

    echo "Test";

} catch(Exception $e) {

    echo "Global Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . " . on line " . $e->getLine() . ", " . $e->getFile();

}
```

Posts controller contains the following:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {

        echo "This is posts controller index";

    }

}
```

Request to "/" outputs "Test" from after the $app->mount($col) call (just to check there's no hidden error crashing the script) but the PostsController index action does not run (i.e. no "This is posts controller index").

Using the Micro on it's own works fine without Micro Collection, and there are no errors reported.

Comment: I think the micro collection does not recognize your route. The '/' is not enough to redirect you to posts/index or whatever it is. In my routes I always use complete controller, complete action and even a namespace. Hope it helps